# Making overlay/ light background on asp.net page 100% height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on an asp.net page and it has a div which appears as overlay ( popup). Html of div is like this:

```
<div class="darkenBg" id="popupBackground" style="display:none;"></div>
```

where as css is:

```
.darkenBg {background: url(/images/blackBg.png); position:absolute; z-index:30; width:100%; height:100%; bottom:0px;} /*added this div after body*/
```

but popup doesnt appear to full height. it goes to mid of the page. how can I make it full page height. Width is fine.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing it to take all the space by using

```
.darkenBg { 
   background: url(/images/blackBg.png); 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 0; 
   bottom: 0; 
   left: 0; 
   right: 0; 
   z-index: 30;
}
```

It would be best to have another `<div>` element inside this, to be used for the content of the popup.

Comment: I might not be understanding what you want then, here's a fiddle where it works : http://jsfiddle.net/pQtrV/